# Scrapy crawler in Cron job

Tags: ubuntu, scrapy, cron, cron-task

I want to execute my scrapy crawler from cron job .

i create bash file getdata.sh where scrapy project is located with it's spiders

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /myfolder/crawlers/
scrapy crawl my_spider_name
```

My crontab looks like this , I want to execute it in every 5 minute

```
 */5 * * * * sh /myfolder/crawlers/getdata.sh
```

but it don't works , whats wrong , where is my error ?

when I execute my bash file from terminal sh /myfolder/crawlers/getdata.sh it works fine

Comment: is the `sh` "prefix" in `*/5 * * * * sh /myfolder/crawlers/getdata.sh ` necessary to execute shell scripts from `crontab`???

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I solved this problem including PATH into bash file

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /myfolder/crawlers/
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
scrapy crawl my_spider_name
```

Comment: +1 Had the same problem and simply couldn't figure it out. You should mark your question as the accepted answer. :)

Comment: I guess PATH should not always be set to /usr/local/bin, it depends on what environment and server you are on, right? So what should PATH be set to? The folder of.... ?

Comment: I'm not a Linux guru, can someone ELI5 why executing the bash script from bash works, but executing it in cron does?

Comment: @MarcusLind gotcha. PATH should be set to where scrapy is located. You can find this folder with the command: which scrapy

Comment: But don't you have to have it enter the virtual environment first?  I'm able to execute my spider with a compound command (enters virtual environment, then starts the scrapy script) but your example is not showing entering the virtual environment.  How are you able to make it run without first doing that step?

Comment: Can you share the complete step by step guide of how did you applying cronjob?

Answer (score 13):

Adding the following lines in `crontab -e` runs my scrapy crawl at 5AM every day. This is a slightly modified version of crocs' answer

```
PATH=/usr/bin
* 5 * * * cd project_folder/project_name/ && scrapy crawl spider_name
```

Without setting `$PATH`, cron would give me an error "command not found: scrapy". I guess this is because /usr/bin is where scripts to run programs are stored in Ubuntu.

Note that the complete path for my scrapy project is `/home/user/project_folder/project_name`.  I ran the env command in cron and noticed that the working directory is `/home/user`. Hence I skipped `/home/user` in my crontab above

The cron log can be helpful while debugging

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who used `pip3` (or similar) to install `scrapy`, here is a simple inline solution:

```
*/10 * * * * cd ~/project/path && ~/.local/bin/scrapy crawl something >> ~/crawl.log 2>&1
```

Replace:

`*/10 * * * *` with your cron pattern

`~/project/path` with the path to your scrapy project (where your `scrapy.cfg` is)

`something` with the spider name (use `scrapy list` in your project to find out)

`~/crawl.log` with your log file position (in case you want to have logging)

Comment: where does the path `~/.local/bin/scrapy` come from or what is the significance of it?

Comment: That's the place where the `scrapy` command was located for me when installing it with `pip3`. Since the plain `scrapy` command was not accessible in my cron context, I solved it by accessing it directly.

Comment: would that prevent the need to alter `PATH`?

Comment: yes, `PATH` is irrelevant when accessing the command directly

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to forget using a shell script and chain the two commands together directly in the cronjob. Just make sure the PATH variable is set before the first scrapy cronjob in the crontab list. Run:

```
    crontab -e
```

to edit and have a look. I have several scrapy crawlers which run at various times. Some every 5 mins, others twice a day.

```
    PATH=/usr/local/bin
    */5 * * * * user cd /myfolder/crawlers/ && scrapy crawl my_spider_name_1
    * 1,13 * * * user cd /myfolder/crawlers/ && scrapy crawl my_spider_name_2
```

All jobs located after the PATH variable will find scrapy. Here the first one will run every 5 mins and the 2nd twice a day at 1am and 1pm. I found this easier to manage. If you have other binaries to run then you may need to add their locations to the path.

Answer (score 1):

Check where scrapy is installed using "which scrapy" command.
In my case, scrapy is installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

Open crontab for editing using `crontab -e`.

`PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
 */5 * * * * cd /myfolder/path && scrapy crawl spider_name`

It should work.
Scrapy runs every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

does your shell script have execute permission?

e.g. can you do

```
  /myfolder/crawlers/getdata.sh
```

without the sh?

if you can then you can drop the sh in the line in cron

Comment: No it writes that permissions is denied

Comment: you need to do `chmod u+x /myfolder/crawlers/getdata.sh` to give it execute permission. that is what the `#!/bin/bash` line does - which must be the first line in the file

Comment: i give it permissions and remove "sh" in crontab, but it still does not works :S

Comment: you can add `>/tmp/cron.log 2>&1` to the end of your command to see the errors. Possibly the script doesn't have access to `scrappy` if it is in a non standard place

Answer (score 0):

in my case scrapy is in **.local/bin/scrapy** give the proper path of scraper and name it worK perfect

> 0 0 * * * cd /home/user/scraper/Folder_of_scriper/ && /home/user/.local/bin/scrapy crawl "name" >> /home/user/scrapy.log 2>&1

**/home/user/scrapy.log** it use to save the output and error in scrapy.log for check it program work or not

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I run my scrapy spider on a raspberry pi, OS (Debian version: 11 (bullseye)).
The following settings/workflow worked for me:

First cd to your project directory.
Install scrapy in a venv environment using:

```
python3 -m venv ./venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
sudo pip3 install scrapy
```

Create your spiders.

Create the shell file (getdata.sh), use full directory paths (including /home/username/etc..):

```
#!/bin/bash
#activate virtual environment
source "/full/path/to/project/venv/bin/activate"

#move to the project directory 
cd /full/path/to/project/

#start spider
scrapy crawl my_spider_name
```

Schedule the spider in crontab using the following line in `crontab -e`:

```
   */5 * * * * /full/path/to/shfile/getdata.sh
```