# Scheduling Python Scrapy on Ubuntu AWS

Tags: python, cron, web-scraping, scrapy, scheduled-tasks

I have a script written with the `scrapy` framework on python.

I can successfully run the script by running `scrapy crawl mycrawler` and it runs in the console.

I can also successfully run the script via a shell script `sh job.sh` with `scrapy crawl mycrawler`.

However when it comes to `CRON` and scheduling the task I cannot get it to complete.

I have tried everything here [Scrapy crawler in Cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235101/scrapy-crawler-in-cron-job) which includes multiple things about the path etc etc.

I can successfully run the `job.sh` from cron and can debug that starts/finishes but just gives no output for the `scrapy` lines at all.

Sure I am missing something simple, help much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you run it in *Scrapy Cloud* from Scrapinghub? See: http://scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud/

Comment: Thats awesome, can you host that yourself? Can I send it to external DB from there? If not I need the answer above :P

Comment: Of course! It's a great PaaS (Platform as a Service). Give it a try!

Comment: Cool platform, keep up the good work :)